# Webservice response is not XML

Tags: android, xml, parsing, ksoap2

I am new to Android. I'm trying to consume a web service that's response is not XML. It's a string. Also my friend who's developing iPhone application get an XML response.
I'm using ksoap2 lib and .asmx web service. Can you please say me how to get an XML response from webservice.
Thanks.

Comment: Have you tested it using something like `soapUI` to confirm that it comes back as just a string?

Comment: What's the format of the string that's returned? is it JSON? something like {"key":"value"}

Comment: @trojafoe i tested it and comes back a soap message @Sheikh Aman it's like http://discussion.forum.nokia.com/forum/showthread.php?69916-.NET-Webservices there's

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the response in XML by using `HttpTransportSE.responseDump`
which will give you the response in XML format.

Answer (score 2):

```
httpTransport.debug=true; 

httpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);

 String ss=httpTransport.responseDump;
```

Then you have to print ss.u definitely get a xml format response.